# Multi site application in Symfony2, all sharing the main authentication

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, session-cookies, multisite

I am building a multisite application which has to share the same authenticated user.

**Example:** I am currently logged in at `domain1.com` and am going to visit `domain2.com` which is part of the same company but just another division. As a customer I want to maintain my session on the other domain.

I found solutions which provide a way to share sessions across subdomains but I don't think this is the right approach.

**My question:**
Is it possible to share a session across multiple domains? In case it is, in what way is it possible and how to approach it?

In case it isn't, I was thinking about creating subdomains (division.domain.com) and creating an alias for it, so the user would still see (domain2.com).

Comment: The aliasing route will probably be the easiest. Short of that, you could probably log a session cookie in a database alongside an IP address, then invalidate records that are more than, say, a day old, with a typical cookie thing... I dunno what I'm on about anymore. I promise it all made perfect sense in my head.

Comment: I would have thought that using oAuth would be a better route rather than having to alias all of the possible domains.

Comment: Do you use separate kernels and separate configs for each division in your symfony2 project? Or they are different projects?